# Google news sitemap syntax

Tags: joomla, sitemap, google-news

I have submitted Google news sitemap for my website using Xmap component of Joomla, i got the notification today as follow

**Your Sitemap is on a site that is not in the Google News database. Google News can only accept Sitemaps from sites that we crawl. If your site is crawled by Google News, please check that the URL of your Sitemap agrees with the URLs of your articles as they appear on Google News, including any leading "www". If you would like to request inclusion of your site in Google News, please contact the Google News support team.**

```
Here is my sitemap:
http://www.thepeshawar.com/index.php?option=com_xmap&view=xml&tmpl=component&news=1&id=1
```

Any Joomla expert can tell me, how they submit their google news sitemap or whats wrong in my sitemap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A News Sitemap will only be accepted from sites that were reviewed by the Google News team and included in the Google News database. Since you got that warning, I believe your site is simply not in that database.

If you're publishing news content, being that breaking news or editorials, you can suggest your site for inclusion at 
http://support.google.com/news/publisher/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=40787

Comment: Thank you! i have submitted the website to google, now they has to review it.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt but i had submitted the website to google news on Dec 8, but still i failed to find any reply from them, how much time it takes for the submission to be approved or rejected.

Comment: I can't really give you an estimate since I'm not working on the News team. Keep in mind that the review is very thorough and that it's holiday season. I'm sure the News team will get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you, i am waiting to see the output hopefully my website will be approved as its a news site.